# beautifulsoupでtimeタグが取得できない

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

python＆beautifulsoupでtimeタグを取得しようとしてるのですが、色々試してもうまくいきません。コードは以下の状態です。
教えていただけるとありがたいです。

```
# coding: UTF-8
import urllib.request, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://xxx"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

time = soup.find_all("time")
updatedDate = ""

for tag in time:
 try:
　　string_ = tag.get("class").pop(0)
　　if string_ in "タグ内のclass要素":
　　　　updatedDate = tag.string
　　　　break
 except:
　　pass

print(updatedDate)
```

Comment: もしかして最初が大文字の`Time`だったりしませんか？ [Is it possible for BeautifulSoup to work in a case-insensitive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602390/9014308), [BeautifulSoup4で空白文字を含んだclassの中身を取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68078/26370) 取得したいサイトの内容をブラウザの開発者ツール等で確認してみてください。

Comment: 取得対象は小文字のtimeでした。他に考えらることはありますでしょうか。<time class="タグ内のclass要素" datetime="2020-08-12">2020-08-11 12:34:34</time>

Comment: `time`とか`tag`とか`string_`とか、その時々で取得した内容のtextとかinnerHTMLを`print`で確認してみてはどうでしょう？ classが関係無ければ取得は出来るようですが。[Fetch date with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29413504/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。time = soup.find_all("time") これをprintしたところ[ ]となり何も取得できていませんでした。空振りしてるようでした。soup.timeとしてもnoneと返ってきてしまいます。他に確認方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 例えばブラウザの開発者ツールモードでは見えるけれどもプログラムで取得出来ない場合はJavaScript等で取得しているでしょうから、urllibではなくselenium,webdriverを使って取得する必要があるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても理解できました。